# can't access variable in view from controller laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, routes, view

I can't access $prospectus in the function show() but works well in the function store() in laravel version 5.6.27

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $course = Course::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'title' => $request['title'],
        'division_id' => $request['division_id'],
    ]);

    $prospectus = Prospectus::create([
        'years' => $request['years'],
        'name' => $course->name,
        'user_id' => null,
        'course_id' => $course->id,
    ]); 

    return view('courses.show', compact('course', 'prospectus'));
}

public function show(Course $course) {
    $prospectus = Prospectus::where('course_id', $course->id)->get();

    //return $prospectus;
    return view('courses.show', compact('course', 'prospectus'));
}
```

the data is passed when i use `return $prospectus;`  but not in `return view('courses.show', compact('course', 'prospectus'));`

here are my routes

```
Route::resource('courses', 'CourseController');
```

`Route::post('courses', 'CourseController@store')->name('courses.store');`

```
Route::get('courses/{course}', 'CourseController@show')->name('courses.show');
```

Comment: i think your $prospectus is null, try to `dd($prospectus);` in show method; or `return view('courses.show', ['course' => $course, '' => 'prospectus' => $prospectus]);`

Comment: Do you get an error in your view? What exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: $prospectus isn't null, data is returned with `return $prospectus`

Comment: i get an error `Property [years] does not exist on this collection instance` with `{{ $prospectus->years }}`

Comment: but the data is passed when i call `{{ $prospectus }}`

Comment: `[{"id":5,"name":"Test 4","years":3,"user_id":null,"course_id":8,"created_at":"2018-07-19 12:46:57","updated_at":"2018-07-19 12:46:57"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supose you want a single `Prospectus` object, [`get()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_get) will give you a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) of objects.

Use the [`first()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_first) function to get only the first match from the database as a single object.

```
$prospectus = Prospectus::where('course_id', $course->id)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that `$prospectus` query don't return `NULL`

Try this:

`$prospectus = Prospectus::where('course_id', $course->id)->first();`

Comment: Worked well! Thank you!